# terminal and ssh-agent/ssh-key

Tags: terminal, ssh

I use ssh-keys to access the remote git server (e.g. github/gitlab). My ssh-key is protected by a password. Thus when I call a git command with the remote, it will require me to enter the password for my key.

An alternative, is to use an ssh-agent. Within a given shell, I could do

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

This will require my password, but then all the git commands following would not require to enter it anymore.

Now, all of the above works equally well within a vim-terminal. The draw-back, and hence my question, is that if I close that terminal, I would need to call a new ssh-agent within the next terminal.

System-wide ssh-agent would cover it, but in this case, I am essentially limited to an access with a single shell.

**How can I get an ssh-agent active for all the vim-terminal for a given session?**

Comment: So far, I am solving it with tmux, one shell running vim, another to run all the git commands.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little `ssh-reagent` function in my zshrc:

```
# Restart ssh-agent after restarting WM or x11 (may be old env var in tmux).
ssh-reagent() {
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(echo /tmp/ssh-*/agent.*)
    ssh-add -l >/dev/null || ssh-add
}
```

This will pick up on any existing ssh-agent processes in `/tmp`; it kind of assumes there's just one running, which is true for my system. After setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` run `ssh-add -l` to list any keys, and run `ssh-add` if there are none yet.

It's intended to "reagent" old tmux terminals after restarting X11 (which also restarts ssh-agent) which have the old/wrong `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set, but you can also use it in your case. You can add it to your shell startup file maybe; you can use `$VIM_TERMINAL` to check if you're running it from a Vim terminal:

```
if [ -n ${VIM_TERMINAL:-} ]; then
    ssh-reagent  # Or just put the code here.
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answers the question as it is, but it provides a work-around.

In a shell, run

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
vim
```

The ssh-agent will be effective from within vim.